# react-native android crashes when debugger is enabled on M1

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

currently I changed to M1 with Monterey
When the debugger is enabled the app crashes.

I also tried to remove the `react-native-reanimated` and tried to downgrade to react-native 0.64

This is my current setup

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation": "^0.6.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "14.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "14.1.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.x",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@rematch/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@rematch/persist": "^2.1.2",
    "@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper": "2.0.1",
    "@types/ngeohash": "^0.6.4",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "appcenter": "4.3.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "4.3.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "4.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "i18next": "^20.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.2.1",
    "ngeohash": "^0.6.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.12.0",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.113.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.29.4",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-slide-to-unlock": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/fbemitter": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node",
      "png",
      "jpeg"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "timers": "fake",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!@react-native|react-native)"
    ]
  }
```

Update:
Tried to run the app on android studio. This is the error I got.

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 7205 (create_react_co)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to run it from Android studio, that should give you the reason behind the crashing issue.

Comment: I tried to run this on android studio. Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 7205 (create_react_co) this is the error

Comment: There is no perfect solution for this. However, you can take a look here (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25494), if you find any fix.